# Run iPython notebook with a specific version (2.7 instead of 3)

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm designing some software that is specifically going to be used by people running Python 2.7 instead of 3. Unfortunately, I'm using a computer that has 3, and apparently there are some dependency issues when some of my colleagues are using Python 2.7 to run code. I'm hoping to run with 2.7 in the ipython notebook to fix my problem. Do I need to install a new version, and if so which one?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose either using the Kernel tab --> change kernel and select python version, or when you open a new notebook under the file tab you can choose python version there.